# How to disable prompt to store credentials in composer?

Tags: composer-php, credentials

When I update composer with private repositories running `composer update`, it prompts to store credential:

```
Do you want to store credentials for bitbucket.org 
in /home/evgeny/.composer/auth.json ? [Yn]
```

How to surpress this question with answer `no` by default? I won't answer every update and I won't store this credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can globally disable all interactive questions by setting the `COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION` env variable to 1.

Ref: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-no-interaction

Comment: I think it is not good solution because it may be some important questions from composer during update process besides question about store credentials

Comment: Well I looked in the code three times and it's the only solution  :)

Comment: Thank you for your research! I posted [feature request](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5107) in github.